# Solve the following matrix equation G*x=b, reformulate as the unconstrained minimalization of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I need to write a matlab script, which will solve the following equation
`G*x=b` where G is a sparse matrix, and b is a vector `b = [1,2,1,2...]`.
Then I need to reformulate equivalently the problem as the unconstrained minimalization of the following quadratic function: $f(x) = $$\frac{1}{2}$$ x^T*G*x-b^T*x$

and implement the conjugate gradient algorithm for finding the minimum of $f(x)$ with exact directional minimalizaion.

I have to use a parfor loop.
Does anyone have any idea how to to this and can push me in a right direction?

Comment: $\min_x \|Gx-b\|_2^2$ expand and solve derivatives $= 0$.

Comment: Implementation of conjugate gradient should be straight forward. There are many explanations of the algorithm online. It is a bit difficult to tell how you would use parfor though or what would be gained from doing it. Maybe the matrix-vector multiplications can be partitioned with parfor, but I doubt it would help you better than the already quite optimized BLAS libraries that Matlab comes with. Might be that the overhead of parfor costs more than the gain.

Comment: I know that overhead of parfor costs can be more than the gain if the matrix is too small, anyway my task is to do that this way. I am new in matlab, can you help me with using a parfor in matrix-vector multiplication? That would be a nice start for further work

Answer (score 0):

To help you get started something important is indexing. Matrices are indexed like (rows,cols) in Matlab.

Assuming N is loop variable, ak is number of rows per in the loop. You can index matrices like this

```
A(1+ak*N:ak*(N+1),:)    % a block of ak rows and all columns of A
```

So for example

```
A(1+ak*2:ak*3,:) * b
```

will calculate partition nr 3 from above of the matrix-vector product $Ab$

Then inside the loop do multiplications like that and store results on their own positions. It may be better or worse to use cells instead and mat2cell.